# Calculate the rarity of a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a country column and a datetime column. Over a rolling 30 day period for each row I would like to calculate how rare that country is in being seen. I.e. what proportion of the time was that country shown in the last 30 days of rows.

To make this more complex I also want to include the rarer countries in this calculated proportion of each row. I.e For each row calculate the summed proportions of all countries that are as rare or rarer than the row in question over 30 days. So if the country in a row is found 10% of the time in the past 30 days but also two other countries are found 5% and 2% of the time in the last 30 days then the rarity score would be 0.17.

e.g.

```
country_data = {
    'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Canada', 'UK', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'UK'],
    'datetime': [
        '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05',
        '2023-01-06', '2023-01-10', '2023-01-11', '2023-01-12', '2023-02-07'
    ],
}
```

country_df = pd.DataFrame(country_data)

```
country datetime
USA     2023-01-01
USA     2023-01-02
USA     2023-01-03
Canada  2023-01-04
UK      2023-01-05
Canada  2023-01-06
USA     2023-01-07
Canada  2023-01-08
Canada  2023-01-09
UK      2023-02-07
```

The output I would want would then be:

```
country datetime    rarity_score
USA     2023-01-01  1.0 
USA     2023-01-02  1.0
USA     2023-01-03  1.0
Canada  2023-01-04  0.25
UK      2023-01-05  0.4
Canada  2023-01-06  0.5
USA     2023-01-10  1.0
Canada  2023-01-11  0.5
Canada  2023-01-12  1.0
UK      2023-02-07  0.5
```

Explanantions of each rows rarity score:

1. USA is seen once and 100% of the time in the pst 30 days
2. USA is seen twice 100% of the time in the past 30 days
3. USA is seen three times and 100% of the time in the past 30 days
4. Canada is seen once and 25% of the time in the past 30 days
5. UK is seen once and 20% of the time in the past 30 days. However Canada is also seen once so we include this in the rarity score to make it 40%
6. Canada is seen twice and 40% of the time in the past 30 days. However UK is seen once so we include this in the rarity score to make it 50%
7. USA is seen 4 times and UK and Canada are both seen less than this so we include everything to make it 100%
8. Canada is seen 3 times and the UK once which is less than Canada so we include it making the rarity score 50%
9. Canada is seen 4 times as is the USA and the UK once so we include everthing making the score 100%
10. We only see the previous 4 rows in the 30 day period. The UK is seen once as is the USA so this makes 50%

Comment: "*To make this more complex I also want to include the rarer countries in this calculated proportion of each row. I.e For each row calculate the summed proportions of all countries that are as rare or rarer than the row in question over 30 days*" this is no really clear, do you mean that you should have an iterative process? Please try to increase the focus by breaking down the calculations and providing your own code attempt (even if using loops)

Comment: Understood. Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming unique dates, you could compute a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) then a [`rolling.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html) on 30 days, then use [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels) to retrieve the count for each row and use that to get the countries with rarer (or equal) counts. Finally, compute the score by dividing by the total count per day:

```
country_df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(country_df['datetime'])

idx, cols = pd.factorize(country_df['country'])
tmp = pd.crosstab(country_df['datetime'], country_df['country']).rolling('30D').sum()

count = tmp.reindex(index=country_df['datetime'], columns=cols).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(tmp)), idx]
country_df['rarity_score'] = country_df['datetime'].map(tmp.where(tmp.le(count, axis=0)).sum(axis=1).div(tmp.sum(axis=1)))
```

Output:

```
  country   datetime  rarity_score
0     USA 2023-01-01          1.00
1     USA 2023-01-02          1.00
2     USA 2023-01-03          1.00
3  Canada 2023-01-04          0.25
4      UK 2023-01-05          0.40
5  Canada 2023-01-06          0.50
6     USA 2023-01-10          1.00
7  Canada 2023-01-11          0.50
8  Canada 2023-01-12          1.00
9      UK 2023-02-07          0.50
```

Intermediates:

```
# pd.crosstab(country_df['datetime'], country_df['country'])
country     Canada  UK  USA
datetime                   
2023-01-01       0   0    1
2023-01-02       0   0    1
2023-01-03       0   0    1
2023-01-04       1   0    0
2023-01-05       0   1    0
2023-01-06       1   0    0
2023-01-10       0   0    1
2023-01-11       1   0    0
2023-01-12       1   0    0
2023-02-07       0   1    0

# tmp
country     Canada   UK  USA
datetime                    
2023-01-01     0.0  0.0  1.0
2023-01-02     0.0  0.0  2.0
2023-01-03     0.0  0.0  3.0
2023-01-04     1.0  0.0  3.0
2023-01-05     1.0  1.0  3.0
2023-01-06     2.0  1.0  3.0
2023-01-10     2.0  1.0  4.0
2023-01-11     3.0  1.0  4.0
2023-01-12     4.0  1.0  4.0
2023-02-07     2.0  1.0  1.0

# tmp.where(tmp.le(count, axis=0))
country     Canada   UK  USA
datetime                    
2023-01-01     0.0  0.0  1.0
2023-01-02     0.0  0.0  2.0
2023-01-03     0.0  0.0  3.0
2023-01-04     1.0  0.0  NaN
2023-01-05     1.0  1.0  NaN
2023-01-06     2.0  1.0  NaN
2023-01-10     2.0  1.0  4.0
2023-01-11     3.0  1.0  NaN
2023-01-12     4.0  1.0  4.0
2023-02-07     NaN  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: @P.Jo you can't use `rolling` on non numeric data, in my case I use it on the output of `crosstab`, which is numeric

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to create a timeseries from you original dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Canada', 'UK', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'UK']}, index = country_data["datetime"])

data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data = data["country"]
```

Afterwards (this may not be the most efficient way to address you issue - but assuming you don't have a large df it will suffice):

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *

vals = {}
# assume index is already sorted
for i in data.index:
    last_30 = i - 30*Day() # allows slicing for the last 30 days
    d = data[last_30:i].value_counts() # get proportions of each country for the last 30 days
    vals[i] = (d.sort_values(ascending=True)/d.sum()).loc[:data[i]].sum()

pd.Series(vals)
```